# Initializing variables, variable scope and import_graph_def in tensorflow

Tags: python, variables, tensorflow, machine-learning, initialization

I have a number of related questions about tensorflow behavior when attempting to do graph surgery using `import_graph_def`. [2 different graph surgeries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nw2ZX.jpg)

In the image above, I represent with bold red arrows 2 different graph surgeries. On the left, there are 2 graphs, g1 and g2, and the surgery consists of replacing a node in graph g2 by a node - and everything below it - from graph g1. How to do that is explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748552/tensorflow-how-to-replace-a-node-in-a-calculation-graph). The surgery on the right, which involves replacing nodes that belong to the *same* graph, I haven't been able to figure out how to perform, or even if it is at all possible. I ended up with this minimal example

```
with tf.Graph().as_default() as g1:
    with tf.variable_scope('foo', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float64, shape=[2], name='x')
        c = tf.get_variable('c', initializer=tf.cast(1.0, tf.float64))
        y = tf.identity(2*x, 'y')

        z = tf.identity(3*x*c, 'z')

        g1_def = g1.as_graph_def()
        z1, = tf.import_graph_def(g1_def, input_map={'foo/x:0' : y}, return_elements=["foo/z:0"],
                              name='z1')
        init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        print(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='foo'))


with tf.Session(graph=g1) as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    print(sess.run(z, feed_dict={'foo/x:0' : np.array([1.0, 2.0])}) )
    print(sess.run(tf.report_uninitialized_variables()))
    # z1 = sess.run(z1, feed_dict={'foo/x:0' : np.array([1.0, 2.0])})
```

This code runs as it is. The 3 prints yield respectively:

```
[<tf.Variable 'foo/c:0' shape=() dtype=float64_ref>]
[ 3.  6.]
[]
```

In particular, the last print informs that there are no unintialized variables. However, uncommenting the last line, yields the error

```
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value foo/z1/foo/c
```

Note that if I remove `c` from the definition of `z` above, this would *also* work. However, I would like to understand this error. To begin with, why is the variable reported as `foo/z1/foo/c`? Why does the scope `foo` appear twice? Why is nothing reported when I print the uninitialized variables? Why is only foo/c reported when I print the `GLOBAL_VARIABLES` collection under the scope `foo`?

PS: I guess that there is a simpler way to ask the question which is, what is the tensorflow analogue of

```
theano.clone(some_tensor, replace={input_var : replace_var})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To begin with, why is the variable reported as `foo/z1/foo/c`?
>   Why does the scope foo appear twice?

After you've called `tf.import_graph_def(...)`,  the graph got duplicated. The first graph is defined in `foo` score. The second subgraph has been imported under the scope `foo/z1` (because `name='z1'`, plus `foo` is preserved from the scope above). So the graph `g1` now contains the following tensors:

```
foo/x
foo/y
foo/c
...
foo/z1/foo/x
foo/z1/foo/y
foo/z1/foo/c
...
```

The first `foo/c` is initialized, but the second `foo/z1/foo/c` is not (see below).

> Why is nothing reported when I print the uninitialized variables? Why is only `foo/c` reported when I print the `GLOBAL_VARIABLES` collection under the scope `foo`?

Since `report_uninitialized_variables()` scans `LOCAL_VARIABLES` and `GLOBAL_VARIABLES` by default, this is basically the same question.

And it *probably* is a bug: `GLOBAL_VARIABLES` collection isn't updated after `tf.import_graph_def` call. I say probably because `GLOBAL_VARIABLES` was designed as a mere convenience collection. Tensorflow tries to keep it up do date, but *probably* doesn't guarantee it always has all variables. The fact that [`tf.add_to_collection`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/add_to_collection) exists publicly supports this idea -- one can add any value to any collection if they want it. Bottom line: this behavior may or may not change in future versions, but as of 1.5 the client is responsible to update the global variables after graph import.

> In particular, the last print informs that there are no unintialized variables. However, uncommenting the last line, yields the error

To fix this error, you simply need to run the initializer for the `z1` subgraph. Like this:

```
# note that it's defined before `g1.as_graph_def()` to be a part of graph def
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

g1_def = g1.as_graph_def()
z1, = tf.import_graph_def(g1_def, input_map={'foo/x:0': y}, return_elements=["foo/z:0"],
                          name='z1')

# find the init op
z1_init_op = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name('foo/z1/foo/init')

...

sess.run(z1_init_op)
```

And voila! You have the duplicated graphs, just like you wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue but simply running the init operation didn't work.

I fixed it by manually running all "Assign" ops of the global variables of the imported graph.

In my scenario I want to run an encoding op 'z' with input 'patch:0' using two different input tensors.

```py
    with tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph()).as_default() as sess:

        g = tf.Graph()       
        saved_model = predictor.from_saved_model(args.export_dir, graph=g)
        variables = g.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES)]

        fetch_ops = ['z:0','init']
        fetch_ops.extend([v.name.strip(":0") + "/Assign" for v in variables)

        image_graph = tf.graph_util.import_graph_def(
            g.as_graph_def(),
            input_map={'patch:0': image},
            return_elements=fetch_ops,
            name='image')

        warped_graph = tf.graph_util.import_graph_def(
            g.as_graph_def(),
            input_map={'patch:0': warped_image},
            return_elements=fetch_ops,
            name='warp')

        loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.math.squared_difference(image_graph[0], warped_graph[0]))

        optimizer =  tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001)
        compute_gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(
            loss,
            var_list=[dest_control_point_locations])

        apply_gradients = optimizer.apply_gradients(compute_gradients, global_step=step)

        sess.run(image_graph[1:])
        sess.run(warped_graph[1:])
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        gradients = sess.run(compute_gradients)
```

When extracting the operation and running it by feeding my tensors with feed_dict, gradient_computation doesn't work, that's why I used `tf.graph_util.import_graph_def(...)`.

Hope this might help anyone facing the same issue.